netplan bond without ip address
I am trying to set a bond to my interface using netplan
the config looks something like this:
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd 
    ethernets: 
        ens160:
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no
        bonds: 
            bond0:
                dhcp4: no
                interfaces:
                - ens160
                parameters:
                    mode: active-backup 
        bridges:
            br0:
                dhcp4: yes
                dhcp6: no
                dhcp-identifier: mac 
                interfaces:
                - bond0

no interface is given an ip address from dhcp not the bridge/bond/ens160
what is wrong in my configuration? I tried to move the dhcp4: yes / true to each of the interfaces but no success.

What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Are you actually trying to create a bond, or do you "just" need to create a bridge?
Bonding, per definition, is the combining of more than 1 physical interface. Since you only define 1 physical interface in your config, it doesn't make sense to have a bond, which is why the configuration may fail (or maybe netplan will ignore, I don't know for sure).
In addition, your indentation seems wrong, since there should also be some spaces before the - for those config lines where it's present (see my examples below).
Finally, I'm not familiar with the declaration dhcp-identifier, I don't use it. I don't know if this can cause issues.
So there are 2 scenarios here:
1: You actually want a bond
Make the bond with 2 interfaces, to actually make the bond make sense, as documented here: (I gave the second interface an arbitrary name.)
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd 
    ethernets: 
        ens160:
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no
        ens170:
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no
        bonds: 
            bond0:
                dhcp4: no
                interfaces:
                    - ens160
                    - ens170
                parameters:
                    mode: active-backup 
                    primary: ens160
        bridges:
            br0:
                dhcp4: yes
                dhcp6: no
                dhcp-identifier: mac 
                interfaces:
                    - bond0

2: You only want a bridge
In this case, eliminate the bond section from the config, and just create a bridge, as documented here:
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd 
    ethernets: 
        ens160:
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no
        bridges:
            br0:
                dhcp4: yes
                dhcp6: no
                dhcp-identifier: mac 
                interfaces:
                    - ens160


An excellent answer.

Hi! Thank you for your answer.
Is it not possible to create a bond using only one interface? (I understand it makes the bond useless). I need to create some kind of automation and sometimes there is only one interface, and I still need to make a bond.
